# userTransaction rollback method in use?

Tags: java, spring, jta

I'm using `JBoss JTA 1.1`

Imagine I have the following DAO method:

```
public void addEmployee(final Employee e){
    try {
        userTransaction.begin();
    } catch (Exception e1) { }
    final String sql = "INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES(?)";
    KeyHolder kh = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
    JdbcTemplate = getJdbcTemplate(); //Inherited from JdbcDaoSupport

    //Some data operations

    try {
        userTransaction.rollback(); //Why can use it?
    } catch (Exception e1) { }
}
```

The issue initially I didn't want to rollbac my changes that were made by the data-operations. Ok, `userTransaction.commit();` is defenitely useful. But `rollback()`... why should I deliberately rollback my changes? Couldn't you get an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rollback is useful if you need to perform multiple insert/update/delete actions and you want them to either all or none succeed.

For example, if you are inserting a new user information and it needs to insert data in different tables, you might want them to all succeed and not only insert data in some tables.

**edited**

For example, you have let's say, 3 tables in your DB: USER, ADDRESS and TELEPHONE. A new user registers on your application, and in your code you have something like this:

```
   try {
      userTransaction.begin();

      //operation to insert information in table USER

      //operation to insert information in table ADDRESS

      //operation to insert information in table TELEPHONE

      userTransaction.commit();
   } catch (Exception e) {
      userTransaction.rollback();
   }
```

Now imagine that during the insert operations for table ADDRESS there is some error and the insert failed. You would want to redo your previous inserts in table USER, since either all the information of the user is successfully inserted (including ADDRESS and TELEPHONE) or you would end up having incomplete registrations.

Comment: May be you give a code example? It's not quite clear to me now

Comment: I've added a bit more detail to the reply, hope it helps. :)